# link_to :method => :delete not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a form, I have:

```
= link_to "Delete toy", @toy, :method => :delete, :confirm => "Are you sure?", :class => "btn btn-danger"
```

This generates the following html:

```
<a href="/toys/258" class="btn btn-danger" data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow">Delete toy</a>
```

However, when I click the link, I simply get taken back to the show page of the toy. (I don't get the confirm popup either.) What am I doing wrong?

I added a `= javascript_include_tag :all` and `= javascript_include_tag "application"` inside my `application.html.haml`, per the recommendation a bunch of the other posts on SO about this exact question, but it didn't help.

UPDATE: this is what is in my `application.js` file:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: Javascript enabled in your browser? Any javascript errors shown in the developer console?

Comment: Yeah, Javascript is enabled. (I'm using other things like jQuery and Bootstrap Javascript libraries.)

Comment: @Zabba: Oh, and no JS errors in the console.

Comment: can you show your application.js files ?

Comment: @Said: updated the post to show what's in my application.js file. How do I check whether those files are being loaded correctly? When I look at the page source, I don't see anything different whether I include `javascript_include_tag "application"` or not.

Comment: Nevermind, I do see errors in the developer console now (not sure why they weren't showing up before) -- jquery_ujs.js isn't being found. Any ideas why? I do have `jquery-rails` in my Gemfile.

Comment: is guess your asset-pipeline is not setup properly. what are the logs saying when requesting the jquery_ujs.js ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `= javascript_include_tag :all` part of your layout. This is probably loading jQuery-UJS twice, the second overwriting all configured listeners.

With the asset pipeline, you'll only ever need to include "application", and never all the other files.

(same happens with the stylesheets)